# Not able to import configuration file

Tags: java, backend

There is a way to import a Launch Configuration file in Spring Boot where we can pass our sensitive data in the development process.

[image]

I tried to create a .LAUNCH file this way and when I am trying to add it it is not visible to import.

[image]

generally in the right hand side all the LAUNCH file will appear.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<launchConfiguration type = "org.springframework.ide.eclipse.boot.launch"> 
<listAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_PATHS">
<listEntry value="/student-directory/src/main/java/com/bma/directory/StudentDirectoryApplication.java"/>
</listAttributes>
<listAttribute key= "org.eclipse.debug.core.MAPPED_RESOURCE_TYPES">
<listEntry value="1"/>
</listAttribute>
<mapAttribute key="org.eclipse.debug.core.environmentVariables">
<mapEntry key="DB_URL" value="https://mysql:3036"/>
<mapEntry key="DB_USER" value="John"/>
<mapEntry key="DB_PORT" value="9090"/>
</mapAttribute>
</launchConfiguration>
```

Answer (score 0):

The way we pass in our DB creds, etc (and I change my local development webserver port, log output levels, etc) is by having a local properties file on our machines in one spot, run the spring app for the first time it stops and complains about DB url, etc then we edit the config it generated and add in a reference to use the `spring.config.additional-location` option in the run config's Override Properties area to tell it to pull and use this file.

Note that when you do this, the contents of this file take precedence over the application.properties/application.yaml file in your apps resources folder.  We also specify this in our systemd startup scripts on the server, pointing at a shared properties file for eureka, rabbit, DB, mail server, etc. info for all of our apps to use

Also of note is that even if you are on a windows machine, using *nix style paths Just Works as long as your file and spring app are on the same drive letter...